# Makefile fails at link stage

Tags: makefile, linker

I'm using following makefile (simplified variant):

```
CFLAGS  = -Wall -fpermissive -DENV_EMBEDDED -I../utils/ -../usblib/include
CPPFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)

LDFLAGS  = -lmisc -lrt

PNAME=Simulator

OBJ = simulated.o \
    buffer.o \
    common.o 

all: $(OBJ)
    $(LDFLAGS) -o $(PNAME) $(OBJ)
```

Compilation works fine, make automatically chooses the correct compiler and sets the correct flags-variable. But the link-stage fails, I get an error message about "unknown command lmisc". So it seems, there is something wrong with my second "all"-statement, make does not apply a default command for linking.

Any idea what has to be done here in order to let it link successfully?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recipe is missing the compiler/linker command. It should be something like:

```
all: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $(PNAME) $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to write your own linker command, it's better to use Make's built-in rule, which is (as revealed by `make -f /dev/null --print-data-base | sed -n '/^%: %\.o/,/^$/p'`):

```make
%: %.o
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

If you put your libraries in `LDLIBS` as you should, you can simply use that:

```make
LDLIBS = -lmisc -lrt

# 'all' should be phony, and depend on a real target
# Otherwise, you'll link every build, even when not needed
all: $(PNAME)
.PHONY: all

$(PNAME): $(OBJ)
```

If some of your source files are C++ (as implied by the presence of `CXXFLAGS`), you will need to tell Make to use the C++ linker rather than the C linker:

```make
LINK.o = LINK.cc
```